# Spring boot how to exclude certain class from testing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2, dialect, usertype

I have implemented own class for representing of database vector data based on UserType class.

My example:

```
class MyVectorType implements UserType {
@Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.ARRAY };
    }
};

@Entity
@Table("MY_ENTITY")
public class MyEntity {
    private MyVectorType myVectorType;

}
```

However this class cannot be used in testing with h2 dialect ie. in memory database. There is error: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003.

Therefore I would like to exclude this entity (inc. repository) from testing but this does not work:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {
                MyEntity.class, MyEntityRepository.class})
})
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

What is wrong or is there any best practice solving this problem?

**EDIT 1:** fixed examples - added correct entity and repository

**SOLUTION 1:**
I think that the only possible solution for this moment is move entity classes (which needs to be excluded) to other package. Then set @EntityScan to scan just non-excluded package. Exclude filters in ComponentScan seems to work only in case of @Component classes, not @Entity. However this is not absolutely best practice to solve this problem.

Answer (score 17):

Just define it as a @MockBean so the real implementation of your repository will be replaced by a functionless mock in your tests:

```
@MockBean
private MyVectorRepositoryType vectorRepository;
```

Comment: I have tried to use it but it did not work. I even used mockbean annotation on service class where the repository is used but it did not work too. Still the same error message.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I had tried using filter exclusions, but that wasn't working. Simple solution ftw!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and I excluded the application configuration in my test configuration, as it seems the test config component scans the application config component scans the classes you want to exclude.

Comment: Yes, I know. Actually I realized this fact and hence I excluded the application configuration with @Profile("!test"). However even after this change it does not work. @EntityScan will scan also unwanted entities...

Comment: Well. Did you try to exclude the ApplicationConfig itself? Not with profile. Like this:
`    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"de.bla"})
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"de.bla"},
        excludeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ApplicationConfig.class)})
    @Profile("internal")
    public class TestApplicationConfig { ... }`